# What is the state of the art method for synonym detection?

Tags: nlp, similarity

In Natural Language Processing and Computational Linguistic what methods are deemed as SOA for similar word extraction?

Can anyone direct me to those resources?

Comment: This should help you. [NLTK Synonym Detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19258652/how-to-get-synonyms-from-nltk-wordnet-python)

Answer (score 0):

State of the art in synonym detection tend to be ensembles of embeddings and knowledge graphs. Embeddings model tokens as dense, semantic vector representations. Knowledge graphs model the relationships between entities and are useful for adding constraints.